# Way to have semicolon automatically added at end of line beginning with a function?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Like in node if I type `fs.readdir()`, when the closing parentheses is typed or auto-completed, if the function call is at the beginning of a line (even if it's part of an object), a semi-colon automatically inserted after the closing paren would save me a lot of keystrokes.

For instance, I may need to add multiple lines to a function, and then I need to hit down-arrow and then maybe left or right multiple times, or click, to get to the end of the statement to add the semicolon (yes I like code that clearly indicates when a line or statement or expression is done).

I've looked through some plugins but they don't seem to do this exact thing, just a lot of other things many of which are not desirable to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an extension that *automatically* appends semicolons, but [**Colonize**](https://github.com/vmsynkov/colonize) for VS Code adds three keyboard shortcuts that insert a semicolon at the end of the line and then either go to a new line or stay on the same line:

- shift + enter Insert semicolon at the end of line and continue on the same line
- alt + enter Insert semicolon at the end of line and continue on the new line
- ctrl + alt + enter Insert semicolon and stay at the same position

Comment: That sounds nice... I'll try that. Maybe I should figure out how to make a plugin that does what I'm looking for.